# MySQL - Pivot columns into rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sum columns in a table and then return each column and value as a separate row, but only if the sum is > 0. Here's an example table

```
…   stuff   widget  toast   …
-   -----   ------  -----   -
…   0       0       1       …
…   1       0       3       …
…   2       0       1       …
…   0       0       1       …
…   0       0       0       …
```

Summing the columns is easy enough

```
select sum(stuff) as stuff, sum(widget) as widget, sum(toast) as toast from table
```

Which produces this output

```
stuff   widget  toast
-----   ------  -----
3       0       6
```

But what I actually want to end up with is this (notice that widget is missing since the sum is 0)

```
thing   count
----    -----
stuff   3
toast   6
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT 'stuff' as thing, sum(stuff) `count` FROM foo HAVING `count` > 0
UNION
SELECT 'widget', sum(widget) s FROM foo HAVING s > 0
UNION
SELECT 'toast', sum(TOAST) t FROM foo HAVING t > 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b586f/7

Aliases in first SELECT determine the column names of the result, aliases in following SELECTs don’t matter, therefor I used short ones.

And HAVING the respective sum > 0 eliminates the *widget* column in the result as requested.

Only feasible for that small amount of original columns though – for a higher number of columns you probably wouldn’t want to do that.