# display data in table from 2 different querys

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to display the results of a survey in a table or other display.  Data is coming from 2 tables, one is results and looks like this

```
qId  rNum
17    1
17    1
18    2
18    1
```

Question table has `qId`, `question`, `r1`,`r2`,`r3`,`r4` fields.  One line out of question table would look like:

```
how old are you, 0-7, 7-12, 13-21, 21 and older.
```

as the information is captured from form, the result is recorded numerically 1-4

When survey is complete the response selected is stored in the results table.

I would like to display the information in this type format

```
question
    r1  count how many r1 responses there are
    r2            "   
    r3            "
    r4            "
next question...same results.
```

I have done a lot of queries and tables.  I am either getting too old or been at this project for too long and just can't get a start on this.

HELP! please...

Comment: here is what I have, I am only including question at this point.  But since there are different responses to the same question it lists question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT qID, rNum, COUNT(*)
FROM responses
GROUP BY qID, rNum
ORDER BY qID, rNum
```

Comment: thank you, I just can not figure out how to incorporate that into the query that gets the question and response text from the questions table.

Comment: It would be better if you didn't use separate `r1`, `r2`, etc. columns. Make a table whose columns are `qID`, `rNum`, `rText`. Then you can join this with the `responses` table `ON question.qID = responses.qID AND question.rNum = responses.rNum`.

Comment: I think I need to go back to the drawing board on my theory here. thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766736/mysql-pivot-columns-into-rows for how to pivot columns into rows, which you can then join with the above query.